# input type="file" returns fakepath instead of real source

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I was trying to store image which is stored through input type='file' but the problem is it shows `C:\fakepath\` in console. how to get the real path so that i could store it through ajax?

```
 <form>
      <input hidden class="coverImgUploadInput" type="file" >
        <div class="saveArea">
           <a class="saveCover" href="#.">Save</a> 
           <a class="cancelCover" href="#.">Cancel</a>
        </div>
 </form>
  $(".saveCover").on("click", function () {
         var img = $('.coverImgUploadInput').val();
        console.log(img)
   })
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to mention you Mr. Phil ..The question you marked as duplicate has very old answer.

Instead of reading other's answer , marking as duplicate and putting -1 is the symbol of your illiteracy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's just the browser's implementation shortening the value to prevent long paths from looking odd.

Accessing the actual image resource for use in AJAX is simple:

```
$('.save-cover').on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    let img = $('.coverImgUploadInput').get(0).files[0];
});
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) about using `files` from MDN.

Comment: What to pass as value? as img returns every object.

Comment: You pass img to your upload script.

Comment: that throws Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation Error in console

Comment: Please share your code.